# How do i replace only required field in Groovy

Tags: groovy, replace

I have two lists :

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = ["?",1,2,"?",4,"?"]
```

In the second list, I need to replace the first `"?"` with first element of a(i.e `a[0])` and second `"?"` with `a[1]` and so on(provided that the number of `"?"` = size of `a`) and the result as modified `b`.

How I can do this groovy-er way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some simple solutions:

This returns the result in a new list (you can assign this result to the `b` variable)

```
def i = 0
b.collect { it == "?" ? a[i++] : it }
```

This modifies the list referenced by `b`

```
a.each { b[b.indexOf("?")] = it }
```

Comment: Thanks! BTW, the first solution asumes there are no more "?" in `b` than elements in `a` (the `i++` index access would go out of range otherwise); and the second one asumes that there are no more elements in `a` than "?" in `b` (otherwise, `b` would run out of "?"s and `indexOf` would start returning `-1`, which would start assigning elements of `a` in the last position of `b`). Some checks could be added in case you need this to work reasonably well when `a.count("?") != b.size()` (both > or <).